# Trouble rendering html in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I've been trying to render html in my react code, however each time I start my page and click 'signup' I get the 'login' view. Is there something wrong with my linking?

App.js

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <div className = "loginBox">
      <div className = "glass">
        <img src= {cupcake} className = "user" />
        <h3>Sign in Here</h3>
        <form>
            <div className = "inputBox">
              <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" />
              <span><i className="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div className = "inputBox">
              <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" />
              <span><i className="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
              <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />
        </form>

          <a href= "#">Forgot Passwordk?</a>
            <br />
          <a href={'./signup.js'}>Sign up!</a>

      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

signup.js

```
class Signup extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Signup">
         <div className = "loginBox">
      <div className = "glass">
        <img src= { cupcake} className = "user" />
        <h3>Signup Here!</h3>
        <form>
            <div className = "inputBox">
              <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" />
              <span><i className="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div className = "inputBox">
              <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" />
              <span><i className="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
              <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />
        </form>
        <a href="#">Login!</a>

      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

I keep getting the view of app.js rather than signup.js, any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Do you want to render the Signup component within the same page or  Do you want to switch another route /signup?

Comment: switch to another route, another page basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
// index.js
'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const { BrowserRouter, Switch , Route } = require('react-router-dom');
const Signup = require('./components/Signup.jsx');
const App = require('./components/App.jsx');

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));


// App.jsx

...
constructor() {
...
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
...
handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
this.props.history.push({
 pathname: '/signup',
 state: { }
});
}
...
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
...
</form>
....
```

Comment: Incase if you want to pass props to Signup component, you can push state to history. For instance, if you want to pass message property with value 'Hello', you can simply do `this.props.history.push({path: '/signup', state: {message: 'Hello'}});`. This message property can be accessed in Signup component from location object `{this.props.location.state.message}`.

Answer (score 1):

This does not working in react

`<a href={'./signup.js'}>Sign up!</a>`

you need to use react-router-dom.
Refer this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for `react-router` and the `<Link />` component. Here is some example code from their website

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
     <div>
       <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component=       {Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
       <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
 )

 const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

export default BasicExample
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic